# Sonar Qube Analysis for DNX Projects

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, sonarqube, dnx50

I am using dot net 4.6.1 and dnx Rc1 Update 1 so i have project extension as webapplication1.xproj.

When I am trying to execute sonar runner, I am getting this project as Skipped one. At end step, getting this information:

```
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Bootstrapper 1.0.2.0
Default properties file was found at C:\adid\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-   1.0.2\Sona
rQube.Analysis.xml
 Loading analysis properties from C:\adid\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-   1.0.2\SonarQub
e.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Post-processor 1.0.2.0
No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed.                  Check the build summary report for details.
```

Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete Sonar Qube analysis.
    20:35:04.487  Creating a summary markdown file...
     Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Details of the build logs given below:

Answer (score 2):

This type of projects are not yet supported by the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, but there is a ticket to add its support: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-167